# Add build.gradle with dependencies to project web in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, gradle

I have the following doubt, can you configure a `build.gradle` file inside an eclipse project? This for dependency management, something like maven.

I have been consulting this [link](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/artifact_dependencies_tutorial.html) in which I can add a plugin to eclipse so I can start working with gradle, but I do not want to create a gradle project, since I already have a project (java web) and I want to handle dependencies with gradle.

Also install gradle on my pc following the [Gradle documentation](https://gradle.org/install).

These are the dependencies I want to add:

[image]

Currently my gradle looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories{
     mavenCentral()
}

dependencies{
     compile group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-core', version: '4.2.1.RELEASE'
}
```

I'm working with version 3.5 of gradle

**Update I**

I execute next:

```
gradle cleanEclipse eclipse
```

But I have next error:

```
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)
:cleanEclipseClasspath
:cleanEclipseJdt
:cleanEclipseProject
:cleanEclipse
:eclipseClasspath
[Fatal Error] apache-18.pom:419:6: El destino de la instrucción de procesamiento
 que coincide con "[xX][mM][lL]" no está permitido.
[Fatal Error] apache-18.pom:419:6: El destino de la instrucción de procesamiento
 que coincide con "[xX][mM][lL]" no está permitido.
```

Any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am understanding your question properly, you are looking to add this dependencies to your gradle project.

You can add them via by searching here:
https://mvnrepository.com/

Log4j: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j/1.2.17

please select the gradle tab, copy the text and paste it in `dependencies{}` in your build.gradle

Comment: Update my question @Bill F

Comment: @5frags why are you trying to delete all your configuration files?

Comment: No,I need migrate dependencies of maven to gradle. do you want show me pom.xml?

Comment: `gradle cleanEclipse` this command deletes all your configuration files. if you want to migrate your maven pom.xml to gradle, please check out this link https://geekmonkey.org/2015/12/migrating-from-maven-to-gradle/